# Como fazer operações matemáticas com um struct?

Tags: c#, orientação-a-objetos, struct, operadores

Tenho a seguinte estrutura:

```
public struct vetor
{
    public float X, Y;
    public vetor(float X, float Y)
    {
        this.X = X;
        this.Y = Y;
    }
}
```

E este código:

```
Vars.vetor _visao;
Vars.vetor _recoil; //Os 2 possuem valores, eu tirei para ilustrar melhor

Vars.vetor towrite = _visao - _recoil * 2.0f;
```

Porem ele está me retornando o seguinte erro:

> Erro  CS0019  O operador "*" não pode ser aplicado a operandos dos tipos
>   "Vars.vetor" e "float"

Gostaria de saber se teria como fazer este código funcionar da seguinte forma:

```
towrite.X = _visao.X - _recoil.X * 2.0f;
towrite.Y = _visao.Y - _recoil.Y * 2.0f;
```

Eu pensava que isto era impossivel, até ver que a classe [Vector2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.vector2(v=vs.111).aspx) suporta este tipo de coisa. Ou seja, como ela faz isso?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Isto é feito com [métodos operadores](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/operators?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

```
using static System.Console;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        var vetor = new Vetor(3, 4);
        var vetor2 = vetor * 2f;
        WriteLine($"X = {vetor2.X}, Y = {vetor2.Y}");
    }
}

public struct Vetor {
    public float X, Y;
    public Vetor(float X, float Y) {
        this.X = X;
        this.Y = Y;
    }
    public static Vetor operator *(Vetor left, float right) => new Vetor(left.X * right, left.Y * right);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/PdijTl). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/4rPOsS). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Struct/Operator.cs).

Obviamente precisa fazer os demais operadores, mas a técnica é esta.

[Tem o fonte de todas classes dos .NET](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Numerics/System/Numerics/Vector2_Intrinsics.cs). E [no .NET Core](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/Vector2.cs,6a55d65498b1ce4e).

Comment: Genial! Eu não conhecia esse tipo de método. =)